# Echo filtered numbers within a for loop and with an if statement

Tags: bash, osx

Desired output: all numbers greater than 5.

One of few attempts:

```
for i in {1..10}; do if ["$i" > 5]; then echo $i; fi; done
```

But the output is:

```
-bash: [1: command not found
-bash: [2: command not found
-bash: [3: command not found
-bash: [4: command not found
-bash: [5: command not found
-bash: [6: command not found
-bash: [7: command not found
-bash: [8: command not found
-bash: [9: command not found
-bash: [10: command not found
```

What is missing?

Comment: You need spaces in `[ "$i" > 5 ]`. This question was asked many times before.

Comment: No, it is not working. The output goes from 1 to 10. Please send a link to an answer that solves this question correctly!

Comment: Ah, sorry, you actually need `[ "$i" -gt 5 ]` for numeric comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spaces and `-gt`

```
user1@machine:~/tmp$ for i in {1..10}; do if  [ $i -gt 5 ]; then echo $i; fi; done
6
7
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i=0
while case $((i+=1)) in
      ([6-9])
          echo "$i";;
      (??)
          ! echo "$i"
      esac
do :; done
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are strictly dealing with whole numbers, then you can also use [bash arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html):

```
$ for i in {1..10}; do if ((i>5)); then echo $i; fi; done
6
7
8
9
10
$
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted